# what is wrong in my vhdl code?

Tags: vhdl

i did a vhdl code for separate  wr/addr rd/addr memory
i.e write the address and data  then read address and its data
,but in simulation it isn't work fine i want to know why??
thanks for any help

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity wr_rd_ram is
port(
    clk      : in  std_logic;
    we       : in  std_logic;
    wr_data  : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    wr_addr  : in  integer range 0 to 255;
    rd_addr  : in  integer range 0 to 255; 
    rd_data  : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
     );
   end entity;
  architecture rtl of wr_rd_ram is
 type mem is array(255 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 signal ram : mem;
   begin
     process(clk)
  begin
      if(rising_edge(clk)) then
      if(we = '1') then
      ram(wr_addr) <= wr_data;
   end if;
  if (we= '0') then
    rd_data <= ram(rd_addr);
  end if;
 end if;
 end process;
 end  rtl ;
```

Comment: The wr_rd_ram itself looks like it should be functional.  Seems a bit odd to have separate read and write ports and not have independent function.  What is it not doing that you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a simple test bench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb_ram is
end entity;

architecture foo of tb_ram is
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal we:      std_logic := '0';
    signal wr_data: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0):= x"42";
    signal wr_addr: integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
    signal rd_addr: integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
    signal rd_data: std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0);
begin

CLOCK:
    process
    begin 
    wait for 10 ns;
    clk <= not clk;
    if Now > 130 ns then
        wait;
    end if;
    end process;

DUT:
    entity work.wr_rd_ram
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            we => we,
            wr_data => wr_data,
            wr_addr => wr_addr,
            rd_addr => rd_addr,
            rd_data => rd_data
        );

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        we <= '1';
        wr_data <= x"de";
        wait for 20 ns;
        we <= '0';
        wait for 20 ns;
        wr_addr <= 1;
        wr_data <= x"ad";
        we <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        we <= '0';
        wait for 20 ns;
        rd_addr <= 1;
        wait for 20 ns;
        wait;

    end process

end architecture;
```

Analyzing, elaborating and running gives:

[image: wr_rd_ram.png]

You can see there's a one clock delay on output when we = '0' on the rd_data port.

While it seems odd the two ports aren't independent it appears to work.

What is it not doing correctly?  Any expected different behavior would appear to be a difference between what you intend and what you specified.

There is one caution.  When using scalar arithmetic for producing wr_addr or rd_addr you can generate an out of range result which would need to be dealt with.  The "+" operator for integers doesn't manage 'bits'.

Meaning when you push one of the pointers to 256 you should set it to 0, emulating roll over.  Otherwise you'll get an out of range error message.

Answer (score 0):

this design work only ,but when i use it for another top level design it seemed to be work in synthesize and in simulation it didn't simulate all inputs data i.e when i use run all to simulate all result it repeated 
i use ise 9.2i program 
the purpose of the design to gave me the distance between data input

```
data1,data2( (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (5, 4, 3, 2, 1) ); distances  --> (4, 2, 0, 2, 4)
data1,data2( (1, 2, 3, 4), (4, 3, 2, 1) );           distances --> (3, 1, 1, 3)
data1,data2( (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3) );                   distances  --> (0, 0, 0)
```

and the top design level is

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test is
  port(
    rst      : in  std_logic;
    clk      : in  std_logic;
    we       : in  std_logic;
    wr_data1 : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    wr_data2 : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    wr_addr  : in  integer range 0 to 255;
    distance : out integer range 0 to 255;
    vout     : out std_logic;
    no_match : out std_logic
     );
   end entity;

   architecture rtl of test is

   signal rd_data1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  signal rd_data2 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  signal rd_addr1 : integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
      signal rd_addr2 : integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
      signal d        : integer range 0 to 255 := 0;
       type states is (s0,s1,s2);
       signal state: states;

        component wr_rd_ram
      port(
    clk      : in  std_logic;
    we       : in  std_logic;
    wr_data  : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    wr_addr  : in  integer range 0 to 255;
    rd_addr  : in  integer range 0 to 255; 
    rd_data  : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
     );
       end component;

    begin

     ram1:entity work.wr_rd_ram
           port map(
    clk      => clk,
    we       => we,
    wr_data  => wr_data1,
    wr_addr  => wr_addr,
    rd_addr  => rd_addr1, 
    rd_data  => rd_data1
     );

 ram2:entity work.wr_rd_ram
  port map(
    clk      => clk,
    we       => we,
    wr_data  => wr_data2,
    wr_addr  => wr_addr,
    rd_addr  => rd_addr2, 
    rd_data  => rd_data2
     );
  process(rst,clk)
    begin
     if rst = '1' then 

rd_addr1 <= 0;
rd_addr2 <= 0;

state <= s0;
vout <= '0';
no_match <= '0';
distance <= 0;
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then
      if we  = '0' then
        vout <= '0';
       no_match <= '0';
      state <= s2;
        case state is
  when s0 =>
    rd_addr2 <= rd_addr2 + 1;
    if rd_data1 = rd_data2 then
       vout <= '1';
       d <= abs (rd_addr1-rd_addr2);

          state <= s1;
    elsif rd_addr2 = 255 then
       rd_addr2 <= 0;
       state <= s2;
    end if;

  when s1 =>
    rd_addr1 <= rd_addr1 + 1;

    rd_addr2 <= 0;
    state <= s0;

  when s2 =>
     no_match <= '1';
     state <= s0;

  when others => null;

 end case;
 end if;
 end if;
 distance <= d;
 end process;

   end rtl;
```

what is wrong in code to not simulate and run all comparison between input 1 and input2 , i didn't simulate with test bench code i use test bench waveform